# Change a struct field when struct is in List

Tags: c#, list

When I'm finding an item from List and trying to change one of its properties, it just stays unchanged.

```
// My struct
struct Person
{
    public string name;
    public string surname;
}

// Fill up initial data
persons = new List<Person>();
person = new Person();
person.name = "Name";
person.surname = "Test";
persons.Add(person);

// Here person is found, I can see it by printing person.name and person.surname
Person foundPerson = persons.Find(p => p.surname == "Test");

// Let's change it
foundPerson.name = "Another name";

// But when I print all list's items, the name is still "Name". So previous string hasn't changed the original object.
persons.ForEach(delegate (Person person)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", person.name);
});
```

What am I missing? What should I do in order to change the original value, which is contained in my list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using structs. Structs are processed by value, so when you write

```
Person person list.Find(p => p.surname == "Test");
```

you get a copy of a person.

Use class instead of struct or write back to list full person struct.

If you still want to use struct you can write

```
Person foundPerson = persons.Find(p => p.surname == "Test");
int index = persons.IndexOf(foundPerson);
foundPerson.name = "Another name";
persons[index] = foundPerson;
```

Comment: Thank you. But if structs are processed by value, there is a strange thing. If I have a List field inside my struct, and if I add something to that list (e.g. `foundPerson.list.Add(someAnotherStruct)`) it will be saved to the original struct from the `persons` list. Why? If what you are saying is true, then the original list should not be affected.

Comment: Because List is a class, so you store a pointer to the list inside your struct. When you get a copy of a struct you have a copy of a pointer inside it, but this pointer still point to the same list.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `struct`s are by-value objects. When you do this

```
Person foundPerson = persons.Find(p => p.surname == "Test");
```

`foundPerson` becomes an independent *copy* of the `Person` `struct` from your list. Any changes made to it are not reflected in the original.

You can fix this by making `Person` a `class`. If you have no flexibility to make this change, you could search for an index, and make the change in place, or treat `Person` as if it were immutable, and assign the modified `foundPerson` back to the position in the list where it is stored.

Your question provides a perfect illustration why [it is a good idea to stay away from mutable `struct`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/335858).